# NGINX error - [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, web, default, configure, kali-linux

I just installed nginx for my lab, in accidentally i deleted default file in /etc/nginx/site-available, then i copy the configuration on the internet, but it can not work with the new config, can someone help explain me what the error ?

here is the error that i got 
[Nginx error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FGS.jpg)

```
root@kali:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:16^C
root@kali:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:16
```

here is the default file in /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            # proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might've to write this as below, server block comes inside http block.

```
http {
   server {
       // your rules
   }
}
```

if you are including this virtual host as seperately in some other conf file. then you have to do below with default conf.

```
http {
       server {
           // your rules
       }
include  v.hosts/*.conf;
}
```